# Error: Expected a value of type 'TextEditingController', but got one of type 'TextEditingValue'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to wrap a ValueListenableBuilder around a Textfield which has a functionality of taking input text and returning the same text. The original purpose is to persist the input data through a database. But while implementing the basic code given below, I'm getting the error "Expected a value of type 'TextEditingController', but got one of type 'TextEditingValue'". Could you please enlighten me on the error?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyTextFieldApp());

class MyTextFieldApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Center(
            child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: _controller,
                builder: (BuildContext context, _controller, _ ) {
                   return TextField(
                     autofocus: true,
                     maxLines: 6,
                     controller: _controller,
                     decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Note",
                       border: OutlineInputBorder(
                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                     ),
                    ),
                   );
                },
             ),
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not pass a TextEditingController to the TextField

```dart
ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: _controller,
                builder: (BuildContext context, _controller, _ ) {
// this _controller is not equal to the valueListenable: _controller above, it means _controller.value
                   return TextField(
                     autofocus: true,
                     maxLines: 6,
                     controller: _controller,
                     decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Note",
                       border: OutlineInputBorder(
                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                     ),
                    ),
                   );
                },
             ),
```

```dart
ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: _controller,
                builder: (BuildContext context, _value, _ ) {
                   return TextField(
                     autofocus: true,
                     maxLines: 6,
                     controller: _controller,// assign the TextEditingController
                     decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Note",
                       border: OutlineInputBorder(
                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                     ),
                    ),
                   );
                },
             ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyTextFieldApp());

class MyTextFieldApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  final ValueNotifier valueNotifier = ValueNotifier("initial");
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar( title : Text("Title")),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Center(
            child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: valueNotifier,
                builder: (BuildContext context, values, child ) {
                 
                   return Column(
                     children : <Widget>[
                     TextField(
                     autofocus: true,
                     maxLines: 6,
                     controller: _controller,
                     decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Note",
                       border: OutlineInputBorder(
                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                     ),
                    ),
                   ),
                        RaisedButton(child : Text("click me"),onPressed : (){
                          valueNotifier.value = _controller.text;
                        }),
                       Text(values),
                     ],
                  );
                },
             ),
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

From the docs:

`ValueListenableBuilder<T>`

> A widget whose content stays synced with a ValueListenable.

> Given a ValueListenable and a builder which builds widgets from concrete values of T, this class will automatically register itself as a listener of the ValueListenable and call the builder with updated values when the value changes.

The `valueListenable` property is of type `ValueListenable<T>`, which is an interface implemented by `ValueNotifier<T>`.

Therefore you need to create an instance of `ValueNotifier<T>`:

```
final ValueNotifier valueNotifier = ValueNotifier("initial");
```

In this case, I created it with type `String` with an intial value `initial`. Then assign this instance to the property `valueListenable`:

```
 valueListenable: valueNotifier,
```

The `builder` which is of type [`ValueWidgetBuilder<T>`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueWidgetBuilder.html) will only get called when `valueNotifier` is updated.

Therefore you can create a `RaisedButton` and `onPressed`, you can update the `valueNotifier` value, which will call the `builder` and update the `Text` widget.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use `TextEditingController` with `ValueNotifier` to handle real time when user input anything in `TextField/TextFormField` like picture below:

[image]

[image]

Ex: For my prj, I'm handling to display or not the Text('*This email not match format ...*') below the Email TextField when the user input from keyboard.

If matched with the email format: hide the Text (red Color).

If not match: show the Text (red Color).

So, in order to handle realtime, you can wrap your TextFormField (with TextEditingController related) by ValueListenableBuilder with **`valueListenable`** is **`editingController`** corresponding.

```
CustomTextField(
            hintText: R.strings.emailHint!,
            labelTextField: "Email",
            isRequired: true,
            textController: editEmailController, // use editEmailController for TextField related.
            focusNode: editEmailFocusNode,
            textInputType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          ),
ValueListenableBuilder(
            valueListenable: editEmailController, // no need to define the variable of ValueNotifier, use directly the textEditingController variable of TextFormField related.
            builder: (_, value, __) {
              return editEmailController.text.trim().isNotEmpty &&
                      validateEmail(editEmailController.text.trim()) ==
                          false
                  ? Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        R.strings.emailNotMatchFormat!,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          fontSize: 12,
                          color: Colors.redAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : const SizedBox();
            },
          ),
```